# Is there a way to create a container for elements in itextpdf 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to create a kind of container, so that I can evaluate a page break for the document in itext for multiple elements.
This is what I would do in HTML:

```
<div style={{page-break-inside: avoid}}>
   <p>Row 1</p>
   <p>Row 2</p>
</div>
```

How would I do that in itextpdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve page-break-inside: avoid  with the [setKeepTogether](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/BlockElement.html#setKeepTogether-boolean-) method applied on a div.

```
Div div = new Div()
.setKeepTogether(true);
```

to add elements to your div simply use .add as in:

```
div.add(new Paragraph("Hello World");
```

This is featured on the iText knowledge base in chapter 4 of [iText 7 Building Blocks ebook](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-4-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-1) under the section "Grouping elements with the Div class".

If you on the other hand want a page break you can add it anywhere in your document with `document.add(new AreaBreak());`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the solution I needed! I didn't know there was a Div-class in itextpdf.